# Corda integration test never finishes

Tags: corda

After reaching the following line, the test just seems to endlessly churn.

```
partyBHandle.rpc.startFlow(::MyIssueFlow, state).returnValue.getOrThrow()
```

Seeing a lot of console output to the effect of:

```
13:28:41.930 [InProcessNode-3-2] DEBUG net.corda.node.services.network.NodeInfoWatcher - Number of removed NodeInfo files 0
13:28:43.862 [InProcessNode-1-2] DEBUG net.corda.node.services.network.NodeInfoWatcher - Read 0 NodeInfo files from NotaryService\additional-node-infos
13:28:43.862 [InProcessNode-1-2] DEBUG net.corda.node.services.network.NodeInfoWatcher - Number of removed NodeInfo files 0
13:28:45.828 [InProcessNode-2-2] DEBUG net.corda.node.services.network.NodeInfoWatcher - Read 0 NodeInfo files from BankA\additional-node-infos
13:28:45.828 [InProcessNode-2-2] DEBUG net.corda.node.services.network.NodeInfoWatcher - Number of removed NodeInfo files 0
```

I know the flow works because a regular Flow test using MockNetwork completes successfully. In this case I want to use integration testing so I can test some client API methods.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue when trying to manually start nodes. There was an error present when starting my nodes, that did not display when starting the nodes through the integration test. In my case there was a missing jar in my cordapp.